# Subclass final static initialization prior to superclass class initialization?

Tags: java, static, initialization, final

I couldn't find any specific SO post referring to this specific case, so I'd like to ask what I think is a yes/no question.

Here's [JLS §12.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) (Java SE 8), listing 6-7:

> 6. [...] Then,
>      **initialize the static fields of C which are constant variables**
>      (§4.12.4, §8.3.2, §9.3.1).
> 7. Next, if C is a class rather than an interface, and its superclass has not yet been initialized, then let SC be its superclass [...] For each S in the list [ SC, SI1, ..., SIn ], recursively perform this entire procedure
>      for S. If necessary, verify and prepare S first. [...]

My question: Does it mean that final static variable of a subclass is initialized before the static initialization of the superclass (assuming the final static is initialized as part of its declaration)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is it *might* be so. The key part is a [constant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) word meaning.

Consider this code

```
class Foo {
    public static final int FOO_VALUE = 1000;

    static {
        System.err.println("FOO Bar.BAR_VALUE=" + Bar.BAR_VALUE);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public static final int BAR_VALUE = 2000;

    static {
        System.err.println("BAR Foo.FOO_VALUE=" + Foo.FOO_VALUE);
    }
}
```

The output of this program will be

```
FOO Bar.BAR_VALUE=2000
BAR Foo.FOO_VALUE=1000
```

In this case `Bar` static final variables are initialized before `Foo` static initialization. Both `FOO_VALUE` and `BAR_VALUE` are *constants* so `javac` may inline this fields.

But you can trick compiler by pretending that final variable is not a constant in this way

```
class Foo {
    public static final int FOO_VALUE = Integer.valueOf(1000).intValue();

    static {
        System.err.println("FOO " + Bar.BAR_VALUE);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public static final int BAR_VALUE =  Integer.valueOf(2000).intValue();

    static {
        System.err.println("BAR " + Foo.FOO_VALUE);
    }
}
```

And output will be

```
FOO Bar.BAR_VALUE=0
BAR Foo.FOO_VALUE=1000
```

So `Foo` static initializer is finished before static final `Bar.BAR_VALUE` was initialized.

Comment: Worth noting: A _constant variable_ is a `final` variable of primitive type or type `String` that is initialized with a [constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).